# php: jpeg mime type – not detected for photoshop jpegs with quality 12

Tags: php, jpeg, mime-types, photoshop

I'm creating a small image uploader form, nothing fancy. Only upload allowed are JPG files – this is checked by the php script with this:

```
$filesize = getimagesize($targetFile);
if($filesize['mime'] != 'image/jpeg') { ... }
```

This works as expected for most jpg files, but I've come across some that are rejected. I checked these images with this site: http://mime.ritey.com/
and found out that it just returns a `"Unknown MIME type"` instead of the expected `"image/jpeg"`.

Digging deeper with that non-working image, I found out it was saved with photoshop and quality setting 12 (not the "save for web" dialog, just the regular save dialog).

If I save this image with quality 11 or lower, it is recognized as "image/jpeg". Next, if I take that quality 11 image and re-save it with level 12 again, it's not working anymore ...

From what I remember, quality level 12 is not officially specified for jpgs, it's an invention by Adobe. So I guess this may cause the problem.

Still, those jpgs are out there, so is there a way to identify them with php as legitimate jpeg files? Is there some other mime type for this flavour? Or some other way to check they are jpegs (except for the filename suffix, that's not reliable enough for my case).

Comment: You could upload an image with quality 12, and then echo `$filesize['mime']` to see what the mimetype is

Comment: echoed mime type is "Unknown MIME type" too on my own server
(for this quality-12 jpeg.  for all the quality-11 or below jpegs, it is "image/jpeg")

Comment: Then I guess that you can't officially support those images, if the image doesn't comply with the standards, you can't be expected to be able to handle them correctly. If I were you I'd look into giving my users an error message with possible causes, one being the arbitrary level 12 quality.

Comment: Guess if there is no other way than mime type to check it's a JPG (like interpreting the file header?) that will by my "solution".

Comment: You could still try to accept them, by checking the file extension and removing all EXECUTE permissions on your server for those image files. As long as you're incredibly careful it couldn't hurt apart from maybe a few broken images if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate the images if the mime type is unknown:

```
$filesize = getimagesize($targetFile);

if($filesize['mime'] == 'Unknown MIME type') 
{
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
}
```

Comment: Thank you – this is what i finally did ... didn't think of that option.